# in plotly, when using error_y to generate error bars overlaying a Bar chart, is it possible to give them their own legend entry?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, errorbar

I want the ability to show or hide the error bars independently from the bars - how can I do this?

I have tried experimenting with adding an empty scatter trace with an error bar, but I can't get it to 'stick' to the middle of its respective bar chart.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], x = [1, 2, 3], orientation='h', name='hello', error_x = dict(array=[0.5]*3)))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], x = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5], orientation='h', name='hello', error_x = dict(array=[0.25]*3)))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can plot your two `go.Bar` traces without any error bars, then add two additional go.Bar traces with the error bars but change the marker color to be transparent using `rgba(0,0,0,0)` so the bars aren't visible. Then adjust the `offset` accordingly so these error bars are on top of the others (useful tip: by default bars have a width of 0.4)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], x = [1, 2, 3], orientation='h', name='hello'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], x = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5], orientation='h', name='hello'))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    x = [1, 2, 3], 
    orientation='h', 
    name='error1', 
    error_x = dict(array=[0.5]*3), 
    offset=[-0.6,-0.6,-0.6], 
    marker=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', line=dict(width=0)),
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    x = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5], 
    orientation='h', 
    name='error2', 
    error_x = dict(array=[0.25]*3), 
    offset=[-0.2,-0.2,-0.2], 
    marker=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', line=dict(width=0)),
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is really close - the only problem is that when you hide one of the bars by clicking the legend the other expands to occupy the space left by it, so the bars become misaligned. Is there any way to disable this behaviour (so that if you hide one of the bars the other remains in place)?

Comment: @tobo i'll see if i can figure out a way around this!